# How to use min-width

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, responsive-design

I have an HTML page that contains a main div "content-row", the width of my whole page is : 1920 pixels.
For screen larger than 1920 i set a  property :

```
    #contentRow {
        max-width:1920px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }


<div id="contentRow">
```

My question is how do the same  if the browser width is smaller than 1920 pixels, it means : to keep the div on the center of the page without  scroll ?
I've tried the property : min-width but no change .
Any help suggestion will be helpful .

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

u'll get responsive Container width from 320px to 1920px

```
#contentRow {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: i've try your it and doesn't work ,the same result when i zoom my screen 125% , i have scroll and the whole page became larger .
Note: i'm working on a SharePoint site .

Comment: if u browser window width 1920px and zoom 125%, all css size larger and not u monitor. )

Comment: it was just an example , supposed i'm using a screen with width 800px ,
i wanna have the whole page in the center without horizental scroll

Comment: Ok. U site width 800px, without horizontal slide

Comment: but use reset.css http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ or next code in begin u style.css * {padding: 0; margin: 0;}

Comment: my site width is 1920px  how to make it responsive with screen device smaller than 1920px ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118646/discussion-between-ysfibm-and-andrey-fedorov).